# Ubuntu 13.04 does not show any icons when i login to ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, freeze

When i login, i just see backgroundimage and Mousecursor but no icons. I have reinstalled ubuntu but still at the same point. What can i do

Comment: Have you tried to create a new user and log in with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics driver is probably not compatible with your graphics card, this happend to me when I installed a wrong driver for my nVidia, so first know your graphics card :
you can log on to the tty session to use the terminal by using 
Ctrl + ALT + F1
then :

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

then download the necessary drivers

after installing restart by

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```